# <picture> is not working the way it's supposed to be working

Tags: html, css, image

Below is my picture tag

```
<picture>
          <source
            media="(min-width: 1366px)"
            srcset="/LP/SpecialOffers/EC012722---ScrubBigOPromo-TILESDesktop content tile_grid.jpg?$staticlink$"
          >
          <source
            media="(min-width: 451px)"
            srcset="/LP/SpecialOffers/EC012722---ScrubBigOPromo-TILESTablet content tile_grid.jpg?$staticlink$"
          >
          <source
            media="(max-width: 450px)"
            srcset="/LP/SpecialOffers/EC012722---ScrubBigOPromo-TILESMobile content tile_grid.jpg?$staticlink$"
          >
          <img
            src="/LP/SpecialOffers/EC012722---ScrubBigOPromo-TILESDesktop content tile_grid.jpg?$staticlink$"
            alt="GET YOUR LIP FIX"
          >
</picture>
```

whatever the size of the window, the fallback img tag gets executed. Can somebody tell me what's the issue here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image srcset definition not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755052/image-srcset-definition-not-working-as-expected). It doesnt use a picture tag, the srcset stuff works similar to this tho, maybe it _is working_, youre just testing with a different set of parameters you think you are.

Comment: How do you know it is not working? As it works for me without any problem.

https://codepen.io/sohebm/pen/MWOWWqV

Comment: @Soheb I checked the codepen, that's working fine. But in my case, idk why but the fallback image gets loaded for all the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Your space characters in the URLs need to be escaped as `%20` in the `srcset` attribute since there a space will mark the separation between the URL and the width or pixel density descriptor.
It does work in `src` because there only URLs are expected and the space character has no particular meaning, so browsers can convert it to `%20` automagically.

Comment: I tried giving %20 instead of space but still got the same result. Even removed space from the file name but its not working

Comment: Try to load the URL from the browser's address bar directly and make sure you did escape all the space characters.